# Too many events

Tags: android, accessibility

I want to get an event for every new notification that is displayed on the notification area. In order to do that I use accessibilityEvent as I show next.
My problem is that I get way too many events. I even get my own application events. But many (most) of them are not about notifications. If the phone is charging I get on every 10 seconds. In the emulator I get an event from my application every 2 seconds (more or less).

So the question is, is there a way to know if there is a new notification displayed in the task bar?
Or, how can I skim all those events that are not about notifications?

This is the code I use:

In the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyAccessibilityEventClass" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
   <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
   </intent-filter>
   <meta-data
      android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
      android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>
```

And the file res/xml/accessibilityservice.xml:

android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
   android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
   android:notificationTimeout="100"
/>

In MyAccessibilityEventClass:

```
@Override public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)
{   if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED)
    {  final String s = String.valueOf(event.getPackageName());
       ShowToast(s);  <-- Too many messages because too many events
    }
}
```

Thank you all